# what is the meaning of suggestions in a Content Provider Uri?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

I've got a Uri as below: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/#/suggestions
What data will it return? What's the meaning of 'suggestions' here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Contacts API](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html) references the [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) helper classes for dealing with contacts.  "suggestions" is the string identifying the [AggregationSuggestions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.AggregationSuggestions.html) sub-table  (note the constant called CONTENT_DIRECTORY), which is used to provide information about how RawContacts that appear to describe the same person are [aggregated](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html#aggregation) into a single Contact.